# Forces acting on a Pivot

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Imagine a handle free to rotate around a pivot P.
Force $F$ is applied to the handle such that a torque is produced F(r) around P.
My question is, is there a Force F(p) on the handle transmitted in the same direction as F through the pivot? The reason I ask is I assume there must be a reaction force preventing the handle from continuing on its straight line of travel and instead cause it to rotate.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force $F_p$ is there, but in the opposite direction from the way you've drawn it (equal and opposite the original force $F$).  On any 2D object, the following relations (i.e. Newton's laws of motion, a.k.a. conservation of momentum and angular momentum) must hold:
$$\Sigma F_x = ma_x$$

$$\Sigma F_y = ma_y$$

$$\Sigma M_z = I \alpha_z$$

In your, case the vertical acceleration $a_y=0$, so the total forces on the handle must sum to zero.

A quick tip on notation, you seem to be using "$F$" for both force and moments.  It is far more usual and less confusing to use "$M$" or "$T$" for moments (i.e. torques)

Comment: Thanks fo the answer it was well explained.